# Coffeescript array ranges without bounds

Tags: arrays, node.js, coffeescript

I am learning coffeescript and some of my code uses the very convenient array ranges syntax.

My understanding was that using `[a..b]` includes indices `a` and `b` in the result and that `[a...b]` excludes index `b` in the result.

Also, I thought that `[a..]` would go to the end of the array and that `[..b]` would go  from the beginning of the array.

Now my issue is, I have some code that needs to take the entire array except the last element. I defined it is

```
parameters[...]
```

thinking that this would exclude the last element (i didnt specify an endpoint so it should go to the end and `...` is exclusive). However in my tests it is looking like

```
parameters[...] == parameters[..]
```

so that  I end up having to write

```
parameters[...-1]
```

which looks pretty ugly to me

am i doing something wrong or is this a bug/intentional part of the language?

Comment: I'm a bit surprised by that as well, posted a question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23184903/no-difference-between-and-for-array

Comment: @jcollum If this is confusing enough people it may be worth filing a bug report on their github. Let's wait and see if either question gets more traction first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered in [no difference between [..] and [...] for array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23184903/no-difference-between-and-for-array), this appears to be an intentional default behaviour. From the docs:

> Slices indices have useful defaults. An omitted first index defaults
>   to zero and an omitted second index defaults to the size of the array.

Comment: Yes that question was actually posted as a clearer version of my question which led to the issue (https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/3452#issuecomment-40976448) being posted which was shut down even though this syntax makes no sense.