# no difference between [..] and [...] for array?

Tags: coffeescript

Edit: [made a github issue](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/3452#issuecomment-40976448), it got closed a day later by jashkenas. So the takeaway is "working as intended" essentially.

```
coffee> arr
[ 0,
  1,
  2,
  3,
  'A',
  'K' ]
coffee> arr[...]
[ 0,
  1,
  2,
  3,
  'A',
  'K' ]
coffee> arr[..]
[ 0,
  1,
  2,
  3,
  'A',
  'K' ]
```

[According to the docs](http://coffeescript.org/), those should be different.

> With two dots (3..6), the range is inclusive (3, 4, 5, 6); with three dots (3...6), the range excludes the end (3, 4, 5).

The two `slice` statements that are produced are the same. Seems to me that `..` should produce `.slice(0)` and `...` should produce `.slice(0, -1)` Am I missing something or seeing a bug?

1.7.1

Comment: Both produce `.slice(0)`. I'm not sure if this is a bug or a feature.

Comment: @amoebe likewise; I may have to open an issue -- it looks like an oversight.

Comment: Looking at @nicolaskruchten's answer, I think it's not a bug. Coffeescript's ranges are just a little confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation then goes on to say:

> Slices indices have useful defaults. An omitted first index defaults
>   to zero and an omitted second index defaults to the size of the array.

This is consistent with what you're seeing. The length of your array is 6 so:

- `[..]` is equivalent to `[0..6]` which would compile to `.slice(0,7)`
- `[...]` is equivalent to `[0...6]` which would compile to `.slice(0,6)`

With an array of length 6, both `.slice(0,6)` and `.slice(0,7)` return all elements and so both are equivalent to `.slice(0)`, which is what both `[..]` and `[...]` compile to.

What you are expecting would be the case if an omitted second index defaulted to the size of the array minus 1, but this is not the case.

Comment: they both compile to `slice(0)`, as I said; it seems like they should produce different output

Comment: I've just shown how the strict application of the default values means that both compiling to `slice(0)` makes sense, I'm not saying I agree with these default values :)

Comment: The docs say pretty clearly that `with three dots (3...6), the range excludes the end ` -- but we're not seeing that. Hence the question. It doesn't make sense for the code to produce equivalent defaults given different inputs.

Comment: The thing is, in this case "end" is not part of the array in the first place as `a[a.length] === undefined`, so it doesn't matter if you include it or not. You can remove the last element with this code: `[...-1]`. Note that `[..-1]` produces `.slice(0)` as expected.

Comment: @amoebe I use that as a workaround but it's ugly and intuitively, `...` should produce the same result. Is it worth posting this to their github issue tracker?

Comment: @jcollum I asked them to reopen the issue but that guy is notorious for being hostile to feedback so I think the ugly `[...-1]` will be the best we will get

Comment: thanks Max; I kinda see it both ways; the triple splat seems counter-intuitive to me but I feel like I'm in the minority so shrug